# Having Trouble Excluding the Company Portal App In Entra Conditional Access, It does not exist

Tags: entra-id

I need to exclude Intune Company Portal from Conditional Access so that a user can sign into it. Otherwise they get the message that their sign in was successful but they cannot access it. I already excluded the Intune Enrollment from the conditional access policy, but I cannot find an entry for the Intune app.

I did this:

```
 #in Entra ID add a service principal for an app  
    
 #enter tenant id for your tenant 
 Connect-MgGraph -TenantId [enter tenant id] 
    
 import-module microsoft.graph.applications  
    
 #appid for Microsoft Intune Company Portal 
 New-MgServicePrincipal -appid 9ba1a5c7-f17a-4de9-a1f1-6178c8d51223
```

I got this as the output:

```
isplayName                     Id                                   AppId                                SignInAudience ServicePrinc
                                                                                                                         ipalType    
-----------                     --                                   -----                                -------------- ------------
Microsoft Intune Company Portal b62ca4ce-2e32-4609-9898-d636316b754f 9ba1a5c7-f17a-4de9-a1f1-6178c8d51223                Application
```

So I assume that it worked, but I still do not find it when trying to add it to the conditional access policy:

[Image showing that Microsoft Intune App does not show in the list of apps to exclude from the conditional access policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKj42.png)